# Url mapping to views in django 1.11

Tags: python, django, django-views, url-routing

I am writing a code to map a url '/products/new' to its view function 'new'. Instead of getting an HttpResponse from 'new' I get HttpResponse of 'index' function which is also inside views.py

My views.py code inside products.py is --

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
  return HttpResponse('This is home page')

def new(request):
  return HttpResponse('New Products')
```

My urls.py code inside products.py is --

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns=[
      url(r'^', views.index),
      url(r'^new', views.new)
]
```

My urls.py file inside the project file is --

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns=[
      url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
      url(r'^products/', include('products.urls'))
]
```

Now when i access 127.0.0.1:8000/products I get desired result that is "This is the home page"
But when i access 127.0.0.1:8000/products/new or even 127.0.0.1:8000/products/new/xxx/xxx any random text after /products i get the same result that is "this is home page"
I don't know what is happening. Please help.

Comment: Apart from when you are using `include()`, the `url()` regexes should usually end with a dollar to match the end of the string. For example, it should be `url(r'^$', views.index),`.

Comment: Why django 1.11? Its outdated.

Comment: @alasdair yes it should be. I did it as well. But i get same result. Don't know why it is just mapping /products/ and not mapping /products/new

Comment: @TheGuardener Yes it is. I too don't want it but due to lockdown my system and other stuff is stuck somewhere else. I am using someone else system which is itself outdated.

Comment: @WonderwareInTouchUsers Ok.But updating is not that tough

Comment: @theguardener yes it is not. But i can't install python 3.x on it for the reasons i mentioned above. And django   2 or 3 doesn't support python 2. I hope u understand my situation.

Comment: @WonderwareInTouchUsers Ok! I understand it now

Comment: *But i get same result*. You shouldn’t do. After you have added the missing dollar, make sure you save your files and restart Django. If it’s still not working then update your question with the exact code (and any error messages in full).

Comment: @alasdair It worked. Adding a dollar sign in both url pattern that is for index as well new worked. I added $ sign like this   url(r'^new/$'). Thank you very much.

Comment: Adding the dollar to `r'^new/$'` is correct, because it stops it from matching `new/something/else`. But it's adding the dollar to `^$` that fixed the problem, by stopping it from matching `new`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this url pattern in your project urls.py

```
url(r'^products/(?P<new>)/$', views.new),
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes I guess it will work. But as suggested in the documentation it could become repetitive when I have many apps. So instead I used the include functionality to include the product's url file.

Answer (score 0):

@alasdair Thank you.

Adding the dollar to r'^new/$' is correct, because it stops it from matching new/something/else. But it's adding the dollar to ^$ that fixed the problem, by stopping it from matching new

So the corrected code in urls.py of products app is -

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns=[
      url(r'^$', views.index),
      url(r'^new/$', views.new)
]
```